# Is there any option to check questions for a specific tag like php?

Tags: discussion, tags

In stackoverflow's [Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions) page, I found different questions of different tags.But now I just want to check php related questions(where php tag used) as I am working with php now. Is there any option here like my desire?

Comment: This would probably be better fitted to stackoverflow meta. There is a list of tags on the right side of the window, and php is listed there.

Comment: There is a "Tags" button right next to the "Questions" one.

Answer (score 3):

Have you seen this page? Just copy your own url address and change last words to tags you like
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php